# emailto body content line break for zoho mail provider

Tags: html

I want to insert the line break in mailto body. i used %0A for line break. But it is not working in zoho mail.is there any alternate tag or encoded character for zoho mail.please help me.below is the code.

```
<a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com?subject=Together%20for%20Success&amp;body=Hi%0AYour%20Feedback%20is%3A%20Excellent%0A%0A--Provide%20your%20comments--" target="_blank">
```

the result will be look like this.

```
Hi
Your Feedback is: Excellent

--Provide your comments--
```

But it seems to look like this.

```
    Hi Your Feedback is: Excellent --Provide your comments--
```

Comment: Did you try `%0D%0A` or just `<br>`?

Comment: I tried %0D%0A that is fine for Gmail. Not working in Zoho mail.<br> tag hide the entire text that followed by a <br> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks for HTML are defined as such

```
<br />
```

Comment: I already tried <br /> tag. if use the <br /> tag,  that hides the entire text followed by the tag (in mail template).for web pages <br /> tag working fine.